# How to do semantic analysis using Antlr?

Tags: antlr4

I am currently trying to implement a ruby compiler.To create the parser and lexer I used Antlr4. Now i am unable to figure out how to implement semantic analysis into the parser.Can someone explain how to do semantic analysis using the generated parser?It would be better if you can explain with a simple example, say how to check if a variable is initialized before use.

Comment: It seems to be that this question is overly-broad.

Answer (score 5):

Well I can't describe everything you can and have to do but I will try to show you the principle behind it...

ANTLR generates a `ParseTree` for you which you can then process with a `ParseTreeWalker`. That walker will go through the parse tree node by node starting at the topmost, then processes through all children (Though that behaviour can be specified as far as I know). If you have registered a `ParseTreeListener` to the walker it will get notified about each step of it. There are two methods for each parser rule in your grammar: One that gets notfied whenever the parser *enters* this rule (before the children of that node are visited) and one when the parser *exits* the rule (after all children of the respective node have been visited).

This `ParseTreeListener` is where you can do your semantic analysis. You mentioned the check for undefined variables: For that you have to hook up your declaration rule, read out the variable name and store it in a `List`. Now you can hook up each rule that can contain a variable, read the name of it out and check whether it is in your list of declared variables. If not then the variable is undefined.

As an example on how something like that can be done you can have a look at a `ParseTreeListener` of mine [here](https://github.com/Krzmbrzl/SQDev/blob/f5ea630c04092640ba317d5065ebea1f62c108e2/plugin/Raven.SQDev.SQFEditor/src/raven/sqdev/editors/sqfeditor/parsing/SQFParseListener.java). The corresponding grammar can be found [here](https://github.com/Krzmbrzl/SQF-grammar/blob/5e72d173ae4bb6eddfe4adf70cb9ea041fd38654/SQF.g4).